# UWP Compiling interop code error on System.Nullable<string>

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP [project](https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10/tree/feature/2-add-call-back)

When I want build this solution in Release Configuration I got a below error

```
  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.App.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(110561,148): error CS0453
  : The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or meth
  od 'Nullable<T>'
  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.App.McgInterop\Data.g.cs(110562,148): error CS0453
  : The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or meth
  od 'Nullable<T>'
  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.App.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(235776,50): error CS
  0453: The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
  method 'Nullable<T>'
  obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\BelledonneCommunications.Linphone.App.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs(235837,41): error CS
  0453: The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
  method 'Nullable<T>'
```

**My question is why UWP generate `System.Nullable<string>` in ImplTypes.g.cs?**

**Update 8/12/2022:**

*As I say in [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10/issues/18#issue-1335892790), I found the problem is from referencing projects to `BSN.Resa.Vns.Commons` and `BSN.Resa.Mci.CallCenter.AgentApp.Data` in `Linphone` project, But I do not know why referencing of these projects cause generating `System.Nullable<string>` in `McgInerop`?*

**Update 8/25/2022:**

*I found my problem is from latest `StackExchange.Redis` package, I create issue on [StackExchange GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/2212) and describe my problem, so [@tommcdon](https://github.com/tommcdon) investigate about this problem in [one comment](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/2212#issuecomment-1220221475)*

Answer (score 0):

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

Try changing the passed in string definition to a nullable field such as `string?`.

Comment: As you can see these code generated automatically by system not by me? so how to change it?